# Flutter how to align the text field left when there is a text field in previous column

Tags: flutter

I am creating a desktop application. I need the second row text field "New Second Weight" to allign like the one on the top "New First Weight" even when I minimize and maximize. Not sure why there is space on the left

[image]

```
      body: Column(children: [
      const SizedBox(height: 15.0),
      Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
              color: Colors.white,
              height: 70,
              child: const TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Billing',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 5,
            child: Container(),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 10, 0),
              color: Colors.white,
              height: 70,
              child: const TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'New First Weight',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 2.0),
      Row(
        children: [
          Flexible(
            flex: 2,
            child: Container(),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 5,
            fit: FlexFit.loose,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              height: 70,
              child: const Text(
                  "First weight exists First weight exists First weight exists First weight exists First weight exists"),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 10, 0),
              color: Colors.white,
              height: 70,
              child: const TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'New Second Weight',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ]));
```

Comment: You mean why is there space on the right of New First Weight?

Comment: second row why is there space right of New Second Weight. How to right justify the text field

Comment: Did you try setting alignment of that New Second Weight container to right?
alignment: Alignment.centerRight

Answer (score 0):

Using flexible and Expanded is complicated, try moving code around, it should work.